# ckeditor5 - Angular 7 Image Alignment

Tags: ckeditor5

I want to align left o right images on ckeditor and I installed @ckeditor/ckeditor5-image

I Use this config on my component.ts file:

`import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';`

```
editor = ClassicEditor;

ckConfig = {
        extraPlugins: [ this.TheUploadAdapterPlugin ],
        image: {
          style: ['full', 'side', 'alignLeft', 'alignRight'],
          toolbar: [ 'imageStyle:full', 'imageStyle:side', 'imageStyle:alignRight', 'imageStyle:alignLeft', '|', 'imageTextAlternative' ]
        }
      };
```

and this is my template:

`<ckeditor [editor]="editor" [config]="ckConfig" formControlName="descriptioncol"></ckeditor>`

But im getting these warning on my console:

```
ckeditor.js:5 toolbarview-item-unavailable: The requested toolbar item is unavailable. Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-toolbarview-item-unavailable
 {name: "imageStyle:alignLeft"}
```

Then I have no option to align my images left or right.

Someone can help me? please.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry it was an s on styles that I missed.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate to add SOLVED to the title or add the solution into the question. If you've found an answer and no longer need this question, you can either post an answer explaining the solution in the space below provided for that purpose - see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) -, wait for someone else to post an answer, or delete the question using the link below the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "style", it should be "styles". :)